# How to extract data from DatePicker and convert it to integer?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, datepicker

that may sound like an ordinary question but i got a little stuck over here. So, i got a DatePicker that display value like this:

```
-(void)defaultBirthdayPickerDate{

    NSString *dateString = @"09-Oct-1987";
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"dd-MMM-yyyy";
    NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];

    [self.birthdayPicker setDate:date];
}
```

I need to know how to extract data (after user chose right one), and after that convert it to integer (and later store it somewhere else, but that thing i can handle). For example, user tap 5 march 1983, and i got an Integer 30 (2013-1983). Please help me, i'm not very keen in this, any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: you can get the date from the picker, then use: `long t = [parsed timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];` to convert it to seconds since 1970

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this below code....

```
NSString *dateString = @"09-Oct-1987";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"dd-MMM-yyyy";
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
[self.birthdayPicker setDate:date];

NSDate *birthDate = self.birthdayPicker.date;

NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSDayCalendarUnit
                                           fromDate:date
                                             toDate:birthDate
                                            options:0];

NSLog(@"Difference in years %i/", components.year);
```